# Weird data binding behavior with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, angular

I am creating a socket.io app using angular 2 on the frontend and I am getting a very weird behavior that I have never seen before when working with socket.io. I have no idea if my code is causing the issue or if it is something within the interaction between angular2 and socket.io, but if it is my code, I can't say what code I might need to post.

The mysterious behavior:  At first instinct, my process for testing if my sockets connections are working properly is to open up an incognito tab, go to my project site, log in as a different user and see if API requests are emitted properly across the users.  However; right now EVERY action that is made on either of the users happens to the other user. EX: if I type into a form one of the clients,  the other clients form will get updated with the same information.  If I click the forms submit button to post the data in the form, the other clients submit button will be clicked as well.  Occasionally, it happens when navigating between states, where the other client will also navigate to the state. The behavior also occurs when logging on to a completely different computer, so imagine it is an issue with how socket.io emits data.

All the clients are connecting and disconnecting appropriately and are getting assigned unique socket ID's.

Comment: It seems like you are sending data to all socket connections instead of just one individual connection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the solution was a bit simpler than I was expecting it to be.  I strange behavior occurs through a conflict with npm live-server running at the same time as my socket.io connection.  I still cannot explain why the conflict was manifested as this sort of strange behavior, but at least I got it to stop by running the app as an express app serving up the index.html.

If anyone could explain why this might have been happening, I would love to hear.